# How to take number input and convert to time in excel

Tags: excel, database

I am making an airplane reservation system on java. i got a sample database from online. only problem i have is the way the time is inputted.

[image]

and some times are 917 , or 22 , or 2. there is no 0 so i cannot just try and put a semicolon after 2 spaces.

Any one know if their is a way to do this, or some work around.

Comment: See my edit to handle your changed specifications with single digit hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
=--TEXT(A1,"00\:00")
```

and format the result as "Time"

[image]

***Edit:***
*I note you have changed your specifications to include that the times may be entered as the hour only: eg: `2` or  `22`. Try the revised formula below to handle that:*

```
=--TEXT(IF(A1<=24,A1&"00",A1),"00\:00")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following formula:

**=TIME(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-2),RIGHT(A2,2),)**

*A2 = the arrival time cell that you want to convert.*

Also, make sure to change your output column to whatever time format you're looking for. Screenshot of results in action included.

[image: Formula to convert 3 or 4 digit number to time format]

Comment: i just realized i had 1 digit and 2 digit numbers in my data. ex: (1 --> 01:00 ) (22 --> 22:00)

Comment: @user17197180 you should update the question with the changed specification rather than posting as a comment to an answer.